# Are there some famous conjectures related to perfect graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, conjectures

I am reading the book "Graph Classes: A Survey", and I know that [Perfect Graph Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph_theorem) (PGC) and [Strong Perfect Graph Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_perfect_graph_theorem) (SPGC) once were famous conjectures about [perfect graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph).

PGC and SPGC have been proved in 1972 and 2006, respectively.
I want to know after 2006, are there some famous conjectures still open about perfect graphs (or subclasses of perfect graphs)?

Comment: A quick glance through Open Problem Garden Complete gives me the following result: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/complete_bipartite_subgraphs_of_perfect_graphs
Not sure I would call it a famous conjecture